# How to define an empty array of DataFrames in Julia?

Tags: arrays, dataframe, initialization, julia, defaultifempty

I want to generate an empty array of dataframes that will be filled later in the code, but I have not figured out how to do it.  Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried a standard way of defining an empty array.

```
julia> df = Array{DataFrame}(undef,10)
10-element Array{DataFrame,1}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef

julia> println(typeof(df[1]))
ERROR: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::Array{DataFrame,1}, ::Int64) at ./array.jl:729
 [2] top-level scope at none:0
```

I'd expected typeof(df[1]) to say DataFrame, but it fails with an error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
df_vector = [DataFrame() for _ in 1:10]
```

or

```
map(_ -> DataFrame(), 1:10)
```

Comment: I was able to do `df_vector = DataFrame[]`, which is an empty array of DataFrame types, or `Vector{DataFrame}`. I added dataframes in a loop with `push!(df_vector, df1)` and so on. Now what I don't know how to do is access column 3 in each of the dataframes in my vector...

Comment: e.g. `[df[:, 3] for df in df_vector]` or `getindex.(df_vector, :, 3)`.

Answer (score 6):

What you have is correct, for your understood definition of 'empty'.
Once you have your first result, you can proceed to fill it with dataframes as normal.
It is indeed a DataFrame array, since if you try to assign any other type to its elements you will get an error.

Note that "an empty array of dataframes" **is not the same** as "a (non-empty) array of empty dataframes".

If what you actually want is the latter, Bogumil's answer is the way to go.

Comment: ah, you're right of course.....  Though there's an asymmetry in that Array{Float64}(undef,10) would not have the same issues.

Comment: @JPi yes, but that's probably mostly a "C++" accident, and probably less desirable behaviour in any case. All other non-primitive objects will behave like dataframe. (try `Dict` for example, or even `Array`!)

Comment: @JPi in fact, this historical accident may be the very reason there's an `isnothing` and an `ismissing` command, but no `isundef` one ...

Comment: an "empty array of `DataFrame`s" is `DataFrame[]`, as this is what "empty" means by `isempty` function. But I think this is not what @JPi wanted. Now we have a distinction between "uninitialized array of `DataFrame`s" vs. "array of empty `DataFrames`" as @Tasos rightly pointed out. Now the key thing is that you probably want all `DataFrame`s to be distinct objects (not - the same object repeated multiple times) - and this what my solution does. You could repeat the same `DataFrame` 10 times using `fill(DataFrame(), 10)` but this is probably not what you want.